# Sirius diagram updation through Xtext editor

Tags: xtext, eclipse-sirius

I am using my own resource which is not of type XMI Resource.If I create Eobjects in Sirius diagram editor it is reflecting in Xtext editor but vice versa is not working .If I try to edit any elements short name in Xtext editor Sirius diagram is lost. I feel my diagram is lost due to Resource is not able to get the updated element based on URI fragment. Plaese help me how i can get the updated element URI fragment so that diagram should not get lost.

Answer (score 1):

When you save your Xtext editor, it triggers a reload of the resource by Sirius (they do not share the same editing domain or resourceSet).

During the load, your resource creates a new model in memory. The elements previously known by Sirius cannot be retrieved: you modified an attribute which impact the URI fragment. The Sirius graphical elements reference the old elements.

If you launch a refresh (from the tool bar of the diagram), it might retrieve some content but the layout will be lost as the (re)loaded model is a new set of objects.

You mid find some hints in the following resources:

- [White Paper on Sirius and Xtext](https://www.obeodesigner.com/resource/white-paper/WhitePaper_XtextSirius_EN.pdf)
- Talk *Integrating Xtext and Sirius: Strategies and Pitfalls*: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_9S5aXAn40), [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/cbrun/integrating-xtext-and-sirius-strategies-and-pitfalls)
- [Blog post presenting several ways to from the Sirius editors or the properties](https://www.nikostotz.de/blog/xtext-editors-within-sirius-diagrams/)